# Create keyword link

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, filter, hyperlink, keyword-set

I'm newbie in SharePoint development.

I would like to ask, is it possible to create a link on SharePoint that will shows all document library and list based on the keyword just like label widget in blog. A document can has multiple keywords. For example, a document name BMW has multiple keywords such as Transportation and Car. And when we click Transportation, it will shows a new tab view. This view shows all document that has Transportation keyword.

If there any possible solution for my case, please tell me.

Answer (score 0):

Creating such a solution from ground will be hard. I would recommend following approach

1. For each document library add a "Managed Metadata" column that is sourced from a Managed Term Set
2. Tag documents using the new field
3. Do a full crawl
4. Use SharePoint search. Modify the search criteria to look into the managed term field.
5. On clicking a term, do another search etc.

Comment: thank you for your assistance Sir.
I want to know, Is it possible to allow search on specific column?